# Trouble rotating object in coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am currently adding a skateboard to my game and I want the player to ride it on his back.

the code reads like this

```
 IEnumerator SkateBoardTime()
    {
        body.transform.Rotate(-90, 0, 0);
        script.groundDrag = skateboardDrag;
        script.moveSpeed = skateboardSpeed;
        
        script.readyForMovement = false;
        script.grounded = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(skateboardDuration);
        body.transform.Rotate(90, 0, 0);
        script.groundDrag = 5;
        script.moveSpeed = 7;
        script.grounded = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(skateboardCooldown);
        script.readyForMovement = true;


    }
```

and I call this coroutine on a button input. the drag and speed are changed but the model remains upright until the very end where it rotates for a split second. both wait for seconds are multiple seconds long so this is very confusing to me.

I tried changing the values of the rotate and the order of the code but nothing fixed it

Comment: what exactly are you expecting to happen? what value is skateboarcooldow? what is "body"? how is it positiioned compared to anything else?

Comment: Can you also include how this routine is started? Is it possible that multiple routines run parallel?

Comment: Body refers to the players model which I have set in the inspector. This coroutine is called once when the control key is hit and script.readyformovment=true. This means that it can only run again once the coroutine has fully finished